# $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); what this line meaning

Tags: php, oop, magento

I am new to object oriented programming and Magento.

I want to know what this line does

```
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
```

That is, how does the PHP code work, and how effect does it have on Magento.

Comment: It gets the head block of the layout of `$this`? Where's the confusion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` refers to the current class you're in. `getLayout()` is a function of that class and should return an object of an unknown class - to see which one, check the code yourself. `getBlock` is a function of that returned object, with the parameter `head` specifing what it needs to return. Odds are, it is a piece of html returned in string form.